# How to set multilevel index in a dataframe with existing columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as below:

```
     A      B     C     D
0    hola   32    43    54
1    hey    87    67    45
2    hi     10    54    89
3    hola   19    34    12
4    hi     11    59    09
```

I need to set a multilevel index using A and B , which is grouped by A
I need the following dataframe

```
 A      B     C     D
hola   32    43    54
       19    34    12
hey    87    67    45
hi     10    54    89
       11    59    09
```

I have tried using df.set_index(['A','B'])
and i get

```
A      B     C     D
hola   32    43    54
hola   19    34    12
hey    87    67    45
hi     10    54    89
hi     11    59    09
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to sort first.

```
df.sort_values(['A','B']).set_index(['A','B'])
Out[60]: 
          C   D
A    B         
hey  87  67  45
hi   10  54  89
     11  59   9
hola 19  34  12
     32  43  54
```

Comment: that worked! thanks , could you please tell me how that worked and why it didn't work in my case

Comment: You need to sort the columns first so that pandas can see it can group them into multi index

Answer (score 0):

Sorting first is not necessary- you are setting the `MultiIndex` but it is not lexsorted:

```
df.set_index(['A','B']).index.is_lexsorted()
False
```

As an alternate method, set the index as you already have and sort it after the fact:

```
df.set_index(['A','B']).sort_index()
          C   D
A    B         
hey  87  67  45
hi   10  54  89
     11  59   9
hola 19  34  12
     32  43  54
```